# Unique Field not showing in Validation

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

my serializer

```
class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = '__all__'
```

my model

```
class Device(models.Model):
     DeviceId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='DeviceId')
     DeviceCode = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False, blank=False, unique=True, default=None)
     Camera = models.ForeignKey(Camera, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='CameraId')
     DeviceType = models.ForeignKey(DeviceType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='DeviceTypeId')

    class Meta:
        db_table = "Device"
```

View.py

```
     serializer = DeviceSerializer(data=request.POST)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
      else:
          return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

but while i am checking in postman , No validation showing in case of DeviceCode , please find the image.. i want to show DeviceCode also as Required filed.
[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh0vf.png)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think it might be related to your model field: DeviceCode. You specified null=False but also default=None. Those seem be conflicting. Did you recently add this field? If so did you do a makemigrations/migrate already?

Comment: hi thankyou @Matt , its working,